# Use Excel VBA file on mobile device

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have created an Excel file with VBA code to generate invoice. I have used both worksheet Events in VBA and named ranges in formulae. Is there any way that I can use this file through mobile or tablet device? I have the following items in the file:

1. A button which runs a VBA code
2. Worksheet events which work on selecting any cell in a column

Could you please help me with suggesting how can I use this through a mobile device? If not entirely this file, but how can I export it in some other format to be used through mobile?

Answer (score 0):

In the current mobile version of Office, supported Excel features include:

1.Create, open and edit Microsoft Excel spreadsheets;

2.Edit the contents of a single cell;

3.Select the format of multiple cell ranges: bold, italic, underscore, font size, and cell background color;

4.Navigate spreadsheets between individual worksheets;

5.Add and delete a column/row;

6.Copy, cut and paste cell content;

Macros written in VBA will not run on mobile device.

Microsoft’s path forward for programmability is to write macros in Office-js, a language based on JavaScript and extended with the objects, methods and properties of Office apps.

There is no “converter” between VBA and Office-js, nor is there likely to ever be one.